# Ink not flowing

Tags: printing, printer, troubleshooting

I have Canon pixma mx397 printer and converted to CISS and the two of the inks are not flowing. I'm not familiar on how to fix CISS printer and this is the first time that it happened. I read some article on the internet and said it is sometimes due to the change of temperature.

[image: Not flowing ink]

The tools that I only have are the ones in the picture below.

[image: priming tool]

What are the steps that I need to do? and
Which of the rubber stopper of the CISS ink container that I should not open during the process of removing the air in the tube and during the normal printing process (day-to-day use)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems one or more of the printhead nozzles are blocked. This is a common problem with all inkjet printers, and one of the reasons why they are expensive to run, as purging the heads wastes ink.

Follow the printhead cleaning steps, starting on page 78 of the [MX390 series manuall](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1148106/Canon-Mx390-Series.html?page=78), on the printer's front panel:

First print a Nozzle Check page to check that the problem does show up there.
Press Setup
Press < or > until you see Maintenance. Press OK.
Press < or > to select Deep Cleaning and press OK

Now print another Nozzle Test. If some nozzles are still missing, repeat the procedure, You may have to do this several times. The Nozzle Test can be printed from the Maintenance menu.

Comment: does priming and  purging the same?

Comment: Priming and purging are the terms used to indicate that ink is being forced through the nozzles, to clean them.

Comment: does it mean that deep cleaning is a better a approach when their a an air in the tube?

Comment: Their should never be any air at the nozzles. I'm not sure what you mean by "air in a tube"

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to describe it properly but I mean like the picture above. That there's a space.

Comment: I have no experience with that system.